# can't get jdtls to work in neovim with LspInstall

Tags: java, neovim

I'm currently trying to get jdtls in my neovim config to work but everytime I open a java file it doesnt start right

the lsp.log says the following:

```
[START][2023-04-20 14:25:54] LSP logging initiated
[ERROR][2023-04-20 14:25:54] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:734    "rpc"   "jdtls" "stderr"    "WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.concurrent, jdk.incubator.vector\n"
[WARN][2023-04-20 14:26:13] ...lsp/handlers.lua:137 "The language server jdtls triggers a registerCapability handler despite dynamicRegistration set to false. Report upstream, this warning is harmless"
[WARN][2023-04-20 14:26:13] .../lua/vim/lsp.lua:1073    "server_request: no handler found for"  "workspace/executeClientCommand"
[ERROR][2023-04-20 14:26:16] ...lsp/handlers.lua:535    "Apr 20, 2023, 2:26:16 PM org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.ResponseErrorException: MethodNotFound\norg.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.ResponseErrorException: MethodNotFound\njava.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.ResponseErrorException: MethodNotFound\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportJoin(CompletableFuture.java:413)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.join(CompletableFuture.java:2118)\n\tat org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.JavaClientConnection.executeClientCommand(JavaClientConnection.java:93)\n\tat org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.JDTLanguageServer.synchronizeBundles(JDTLanguageServer.java:414)\n\tat org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.JDTLanguageServer$2.run(JDTLanguageServer.java:301)\n\tat org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)\nCaused by: org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.ResponseErrorException: MethodNotFound\n\tat org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint.handleResponse(RemoteEndpoint.java:209)\n\tat org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint.consume(RemoteEndpoint.java:193)\n\tat org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.ParentProcessWatcher.lambda$1(ParentProcessWatcher.java:144)\n\tat org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.StreamMessageProducer.handleMessage(StreamMessageProducer.java:194)\n\tat org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.StreamMessageProducer.listen(StreamMessageProducer.java:94)\n\tat org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.ConcurrentMessageProcessor.run(ConcurrentMessageProcessor.java:113)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:577)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)\n"
```

- I tried changing my jdk version from the latest to 17
- I tried manually installing jdtls and configuring it without the lsp and mason plugin

Comment: I have the same issue. would love to see the solution if found :/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like jdtls is crashing during startup.

I ran into this issue after partially cleaning up my environment. Jdtls would crash when it tried to load jar's that were deleted and throw the above error. I fixed it by clearing the eclipse cache (`'-data', workspace_folder` input to jdtls command is the location)

For further root causing, since it is jdtls that is crashing and not the lsp, you'll need to get the log output from java by passing in `'-Xlog::file=' .. home .. '/logs/test.log', '-verbose'` during startup.